# Square-weird numbers

Tags: number-theory

[Weird numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeirdNumber.html)

This is motivated by group theory, where not divisors of a number sum to it, but their squares. (Irrep dims and group order, for example $1^2+1^2+1^2+3^2=12$ for $A_4$ - those are the complex irreps, the real irreps are $1,2,3$ but of course the squares sum to $14$, see comment...).

Thus call a number $n$ square-weird iff no subset of the proper divisors add to $n$ when squared.

An easy way to construct non-square-weird numbers:

$2^2+3^2=13$

$(2^2*3^2)*(2^2+3^2)=(2*2*3)^2+(2*3*3)^2=2^2*3^2*13$

$2*2*3|2^2*3^2*13$, same for 3

$2^2*3^2*13$ is non-square-weird

But can a non-square-weird number be squarefree? Yes:

$1^2+2^2+3^2+14^2=2*3*5*7=210$

Can you somehow describe the non-square-weird numbers nearer, especially if it can be of the form $p_1*p_2*p_3$? (Since prime powers and products of two primes obviously can't be non-square-weird.)

For computing a list of non-square-weird numbers, [this Mathematica proggie](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73301/calculating-weird-numbers) should be easily adaptable.

Comment: Be clearer on the rules you want to follow: e.g. why have you dropped a factor of 2 from $1^2+2^2+3^2+14^2\ne2^2*3*5*7=420$ and rules on additional factors $5$ in this case.

Comment: In standard Algebra $1^2+2^2+3^2=1+4+9=14\eq 12$, and $3\ndiv 14$.

Comment: If I do not miss something , an example for $p_1\cdot p_2\cdot p_3$ is $30=5^2+2^2+1^2$

Comment: @R.J.Mathar: I can't compute, but that very fast :-) (The reason for my foulup is that the real irrep $2$ splits into two complex irreps $1+1$, and indeed $1^2+1^2+1^2+3^2=12$ as it should be. Confused that again.)

Comment: @Peter: Could have found that (just checking the smallest example possible) myself, but you see how good I can calculate in my head :-)

Comment: Remark 1: The terminology "iff no subset of the proper divisors" excludes cases like 1^2+1^2+1^2+3^2 with the strict terminology that  
a subset cannot contain an element more than once (here the 1 occurs
three times on the l.h.s.).
Remark 2: See https://oeis.org/A066213 for non-square-weird numbers under the strict terminology.

Comment: Good find! I knew that someone had already thought of it. especially considering the connection to group theory.